# Arcpy publish failing staging after analysis passed

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server

I have code (that has been working) to publish a map document.  What's happening today (never seen before), is that the analysis (AnalyzeForSD()) is working without error, but I staging (StageService) is failing with 'Error 001272: Analyzer errors were encountered (codes=1,2)'.

So, several odd things happening there.  First, I looked up [those codes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/publish-map-services/00001-data-frame-does-not-have-layers.htm), and those indicate that 1) no data is present in the data frame, and 2) no spatial reference is set.  AnalyzeForSD() should indicate either of those errors (I have seen both before from that).

Second, I did check the DataFrame (and there is only one of those), and did find all the layers I expected there.  Third, I also verified that all those layers were connected to a valid data source (via ListBrokenDataSources()).  Fourth, after the script finishes, I can re-open the MXD in ArcMap Desktop, and see everything there. (And the script and ArcMap are both being run as the same user, which should (I think) eliminate the possibility of a permissions issue.)

Finally, I can publish from that MXD within ArcMap.

Anyone have any ideas what I can try?

Comment: The server might not have access to the data.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have any idea why, but changing the MXD to store absolute references to data, rather than relative, fixed the problem.

So my publish code now opens the mxd, sets mxd.relativePaths to False (it had to be True in an earlier step), saves the mxd (even though there is no closing of the mxd before publishing, this is required), then goes on to the main publishing code.